# summing entries in a variable based on another variable(make unique) in python lists

Tags: python, arrays, csv, count, bigdata

i have a question as to how i can perform this task in python:-

i have an array of entries like:
[IPAddress, connections, policystatus, activity flag, longitude, latitude] (all as strings)

ex.

```
['172.1.21.26','54','1','2','31.15424','12.54464']
['172.1.21.27','12','2','4','31.15424','12.54464']
['172.1.27.34','40','1','1','-40.15474','-54.21454']
['172.1.2.45','32','1','1','-40.15474','-54.21454']
```

...
till about 110000 entries with about 4000 different combinations of longitude-latitude

i want to count the average connections, average policy status,average of activity flag for each location

something like this:

```
[longitude,latitude,avgConn,avgPoli,avgActi]
['31.15424','12.54464','33','2','3']
['-40.15474','-54.21454','31','1','1']
```

...
so on

and i have about 195 files with ~110,000 entries each (sort of a big data problem)
my files are in .csv but im using it as .txt to easily work with it in python(not sure if this is the best idea)

im still new to python so im not really sure whats the best approach to use but i sincerely appreciate any help or guidance for this problem

thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should consider loading your csv files into a database

Comment: Yep, 195*110000 data sets seems like an amount of data that is not delightfully worked with in Python.

Comment: well, i do intend to use sqlite but i just wanted to know if this is possible on python. as i havnt used sqlite before, i wanted to know if i can do it in python itself as i still have to learn how to work with dbs

Answer (score 0):

No, if you have the files as .csv, threating them as text does not make sense, since python ships with the excellent `csv` module.
You could read the csv rows into a `dict` to group them, but I'd suggest writing the data in a proper database, and use SQL's `AVG()` and `GROUP BY`. Python ships with bindings for most databaases. If you have none installed, consider using the `sqlite` module.

Answer (score 0):

I'll only give you the algorithm, you would learn more by writing the actual code yourself.

Use a Dictionary, with the key as a pair of the form `(longitude, latitude)` and value as a list of the for `[ConnectionSum,policystatusSum,ActivityFlagSum]`

1. loop over the entries once (do count the total number of entries, **N**)
2. a. for each entry, if the location exists - add the conn, policystat and Activity value to the existing sum.

   b. if the entry does not exist, then assign [0,0,0] as the value
3. Do 1 and 2 for all files.
4. After all the entries have been scanned. Loop over the dictionary and divide each element of the list `[ConnectionSum,policystatusSum,ActivityFlagSum]` by **N** to get the average values of each.

Comment: "loop over the entries once" could well be the bottleneck here :)

Answer (score 0):

As long as your locations are restricted to being in the same files (or even close to each other in a file), all you need to do is the stream-processing paradigm. For example if you know that duplicate locations only appear in a file, read each file, calculate the averages, then close the file. As long as you let the old data float out of scope, the garbage collector will get rid of it for you. Basically do this:

```
def processFile(pathToFile):
    ...

totalResults = ...
for path in filePaths:
    partialResults = processFile(path)
    totalResults = combine...partialResults...with...totalResults
```

An even more elegant solution would be to use the O(1) method of calculating averages "on-line". If for example you are averaging 5,6,7, you would do `5/1=5.0`, `(5.0*1+6)/2=5.5`, `(5.5*2+7)/3=6`. At each step, you only keep track of the current average and the number of elements. This solution will yield the minimal amount of memory used (no more than the size of your final result!), and doesn't care about which order you visit elements in. It would go something like this. See http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html for what functions you'll need in the CSV module.

```
import csv

def allTheRecords():
    for path in filePaths:
        for row in csv.somehow_get_rows(path):
            yield SomeStructure(row)

averages = {}  # dict: keys are tuples (lat,long), values are an arbitrary
               # datastructure, e.g. dict, representing {avgConn,avgPoli,avgActi,num}

for record in allTheRecords():
    position = (record.lat, record.long)
    currentAverage = averages.get(position, default={'avgConn':0, 'avgPoli':0, 'avgActi':0, num:0})
    newAverage = {apply the math I mentioned above}
    averages[position] = newAverage
```

(Do note that the notion of an "average at a location" is not well-defined. Well, it is well-defined, but not very useful: If you knew the exactly location of every IP event to infinite precision, the average of everything would be itself. The only reason you can compress your dataset is because your latitude and longitude have finite precision. If you run into this issue if you acquire more precise data, you can choose to round to the appropriate precision. It may be reasonable to round to within 10 meters or something; see latitude and longitude. This requires just a little bit of math/geometry.)